# sharepoint - web part error

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I encountered this error

Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type ABC.Home.Webpart.FeatureNews.FeatureNews, ABC.Home.Webpart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9e9b8c88cd4e6428 could not be found or it is not registered as safe. Correlation ID: 6db8219e-b3f4-80d4-aa23-266815f8865f.

I have registered the web part as safe in the config file.

```
<SafeControl Assembly="ABC.Home.Webpart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9e9b8c88cd4e6428" Namespace="ABC.Home.Webpart.FeatureNews" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try retracting your solution and delete your web part from Web Part Gallery. Clean, rebuild and deploy your project again.

This issue may raised due to WebPart name change after creation or change made in namespace. Also ensure an IIS reset.

Comment: the solution I have found by myself. Thank you.